# How to get the Parent Id on a Category Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello I need some help from you. I want to get the parent id and category id  and save it on my db.

**Category db:**

id - 1

parent - 0 (zero value since it is the main cat)

catname - Sample

id - 2

parent - 1 (1 is value since it is a child cat of Sample)

catname - Sample 2

Now I want to get both Parent Id and Cat... My Category display both on the select field only the child category will have a "--" value before the category name.

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">- Select Category -</option>
                        <?php foreach ($listThreadsCat as $row) {
                        $sub = ($row->parent!=0)?'--':'';
                        $sel = (set_value('category')==$row->id)?'selected="selected"':'';
                        ?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" <?php echo $sel;?>><?php echo $sub.$row->catname; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
```

Comment: or because `$listThreadsCat` has both just use the child category to lookup the parent, then you dont need to POST it up.

Comment: I cannot set a parent because its just like a forum... the codes is working fine I`m just having a trouble if how I will save into db the parent id value since the selection can only get the cat id value... the parent id and cat id is on the same table.

Comment: I don't understand. Even after you explain it. You have all the information from the list array. Use the submitted ID to recreate or get the parent. This is simple array manipulation.

Comment: Actually I`m have trouble to explain it but by the I figure it out and its already working.. Thanks dude for your effort to give a response to me.!